# Copying range of cells into last empty row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently working on VBA code to copy a range of cells from another workbook if a worksheet area = 1. I was able to get the first for loop working and pasting correctly.

First for loop:

```
    dataMap.Range("B3:G24").Copy
    
    For i = 6 To 25
    
        If requiredTemplates.Range("Y" & i).Value <> 1 Then
        
        j = j + 7
        
        End If
    
        If requiredTemplates.Range("Y" & i).Value = 1 Then
            
            dataMapTarget.Range("A2:F23").Offset(0, j).PasteSpecial
            j = j + 7
            
        End If
        
    Next i
```

My issue is my second for loop. I'm trying to look at a different worksheet to paste directly after the next empty 'row.' Here is the code:

```
    For i = 6 To 25
    
        If requiredTemplates.Range("Z" & i).Value <> 1 Then
        
            j = j + 7
        
        End If
    
    
        If requiredTemplates.Range("Z" & i).Value = 1 Then
                
            dataMapTarget.Cells(Columns.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, j).PasteSpecial
            j = j + 7
            
        End If
        
    Next i
```

This is the following result:

pasteresult

[image: 1]

The first 'range area' was copied over correctly. However the second 'range' area looks like it has been offsett to paste in the next empty row and will paste the next 10+ in the same row. I want it all to be uniform in the same row.

Any suggestions or tips greatly appreciated!

I tried changing "dataMapTarget.Cells(Columns.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, j).PasteSpecial" to this:
"dataMapTarget.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).Offset(0, j).End(xlUp).PasteSpecial"

I switched '.End(xlUp)' and 'Offset(1,j) positions. This ensured that they were all lined up. Image:

rows and offset change

[image: 2]

However, I was not able to offset the row by 1 lower. I received an error if I tried to change the offset to (1, j)

- rune-time error '1004' -- application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: To find the last row - this chap shows the various techniques with the pros and cons - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DpwAO5qnvAQ
Instead of using `PasteSpecial` just assign the value of the target range to be the value of the source range - much safer

Answer (score 0):

Please try.

```vb
dataMapTarget.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial
```

- `Cells(Rows.Count, 1)` is the last cell of col A
- `End(xlUp)` gets the last cell which has contents
- `Offset(0, 1)` get the (blank) cell which is below the last cell
- btw, `Cells(Columns.Count, 1)` doesn't make any sense. `Columns.Count` returns the columns count on worksheet.